# Unity accessing Firebase database causes Editor to crash

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I followed this video to setup my Unity project with Firebase:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6du3DUTIPI&feature=emb_title

Everything is good at this point and I can also see my activity in the Analytics dashboard, so I'm fairly confident that my environment is setup ok.

It all seems to fall apart when I try to access my database. I'll hit the play button and then the whole editor has a fatal crash. I have NO idea what's going on! Following simple examples to read from the database always results in a crash. Here's how I'm trying to access it so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Firebase.Extensions;

public class FirebaseUtils : MonoBehaviour
{
    private FirebaseDatabase _database;
    public UnityEvent OnFirebaseInitialized = new UnityEvent();

    private void Start() {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            Debug.Log("Firebase init");
            if (task.Exception != null) {
                Debug.LogError($"Failed to initialize Firebase with {task.Exception}");
                return;
            }
            OnFirebaseInitialized.Invoke();
        });
    }

    public void FirebaseReady() {
        Debug.Log("Firebase is ready");
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://myproject.firebaseio.com/");
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference; // CRASHES HERE
    }
}
```

I managed to take a screenshot of the console right before the Editor shuts down.
[image: error message]

Please, what in the world is happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/807

So go into your player settings and look for your package name. You must create a folder with the same package name in your AppData. So for example, if my package name was `com.GreenCell.firebase` then I need to create this folder: `C:\Users[yourUsername]\AppData\Local\com.GreenCell.firebase`.

If this folder is missing it will straight up crash the Editor on run. Very lame, but I hope it saves someone the same headache.

Comment: That folder exists regardless. The package creates it for you. You can delete it before hitting play every time and it will still create that folder for you.